# Is it a good idea to declare some private methods as static when they don't rely on the instance?

Tags: java, performance, coding-style

I have an habit : if a private method in a class, don't need to use instance properties, then I consider this method as helper / tool method, and declare it as static.

Is it a good idea ? did something change in term of code size, or in term of execution performance, or within the class cache of the JVM ? I was told that in C++ this could be a problem, so do it in Java ?

Sample :

```
public class MyClass
{
    .....

    private int add(final int a, final int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Become :

```
public class MyClass
{
    .....

    private static int add(final int a, final int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an irrelevant detail. You can be certain that performance has nothing to do with it, and if it did, it would be useless micro-optimization.

Comment: imho it is good practice to add `static` since it *expresses* the design decision that the method does not rely on an object context.

Comment: Btw, this is nice article about why utility classes are not the best practice in object oriented design - [link](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html). Maybe you'll find it useful

Comment: Thanks for the link. But here MyClass is not an utility class, it is a normal class, but 1 (or more) private method could be declared as static.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea or a bad idea. The change would be microscopic if not non-existent (I'd bet on the latter of the two), so you're probably wasting your time scrutinizing a detail like that.

That being said, it can also tell you (the programmer) which of your methods require an instance, and which don't. You could also use a comment for that though..